# JAGS Error: Invalid Parent Values on last observation

Tags: logistic, bayesian, jags

I am using R2jags to fit a model in R using JAGS. Here is my code:

```
predictorNames <- c("BMIX", "AGE", "TEXPWK", "FRUITS", "VEGTABLS", 
                    "FISH", "REDMEAT", "POULTRY", "SOY", "NUTS", "GRAINS", 
                    "WHLGRNS", "MILKS", "DAIRY", "RACE.BLACK", "REGION.NE", 
                    "REGION.MW", "REGION.S", "SMOKING.PAST", "SMOKING.CURRENT",
                    "ALCOHOL.PAST", "ALCOHOL.CURRENT", "TOTHSTAT.LOW",
                    "TOTHSTAT.HIGH")
nPredictors <- length(predictorNames)

y <- as.vector(dummyData.iT2D$iT2D)
x <- as.matrix(dummyData.iT2D[, predictorNames])

jagsData <- list(x = x, y = y, N = nrow(dummyData.iT2D), nP = nPredictors)
jagsParams <- character(nPredictors+1)
jagsParams[1] <- "b0"
for(eachParam in 1:(length(jagsParams)-1)) {
    jagsParams[eachParam+1] <- paste("b", eachParam, sep="")
}

jagsModel <- function() {
    for(i in 1:N) {
        y[i] ~ dbern(mu[i])
        mu[i] <- 1/1+exp(-(b0+inprod(b[], x[i, ])))
    }
    b0 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-6)
    for(j in 1:nP) {
        b[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-6)
    }
}

jagsFit1 <- jags(data=jagsData, parameters.to.save=jagsParams, n.iter=110000,
                 n.thin=10, n.burnin=10000, model.file=jagsModel)
```

However, when I try to fit the model, I get

```
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
   Graph Size: 286683

Initializing model
Deleting model

Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  Error in node y[9247]
Invalid parent values
```

9247 is the number of observations I have in my dataset. When I remove this observation, the same thing occurs, but at 9246 (which would be the last observation in the dataset again). Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: Does `y` contain 0/1 only ? Or rather there is a parenthesis problem in `mu[i] <- 1/1+exp(...` which should be `mu[i] <- 1/(1+exp(...`.

Comment: Ah, thank you... Did not realize how trivial the solution was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that mu[9247] is evaluating outside the range [0,1] at initialisation, because there is a mistake on the regression line.  You could correct the parentheses as instructed by Stéphane Laurent, but it would be more usual to write this type of GLM as:

```
 logit(mu[i]) <- b0 + .....
```

Also remember to load the glm module which will give you block updating of your parameters and therefore (hopefully) better convergence.

Matt